# How can I automatically render the many script tags depending on environment using the new Asp BundlerMinifier?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gulp, bundling-and-minification

At the moment, I am using the NuGet package which allows me to define large bundles with many JS files,

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/js/PartOfMyGiantAngularApp").Include(
  // messages
                    "~/App/messages/service/messageCache.module.js",
                    "~/App/messages/service/messageCache.service.js",
                    "~/App/messages/message-list/message-list.module.js",
                    "~/App/messages/message-list/message-list.component.js",
                    "~/App/messages/message-detail/message-detail.module.js",
                    "~/App/messages/message-detail/message-detail.component.js",
                    "~/App/messages/message-edit/message-edit.module.js",
                    "~/App/messages/message-edit/message-edit.component.js",
                    "~/App/messages/message-create/message-create.module.js",
                    "~/App/messages/message-create/message-create.component.js",
                    "~/App/messages/message.module.js"
)
```

and the pull them all into my main html file:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/js/PartOfMyGiantAngularApp.js")
```

Which will either produce one file in production:

```
<script src="/Bundles/js/PartOfMyGiantAngularApp.js"></script>
```

, or in dev it will render multiple script tags.

```
<script src="/App/messages/service/messageCache.module.js"></script>
<script src="/App/messages/service/messageCache.service.js"></script>
<script src="/App/messages/message-list/message-list.module.js"></script>
<script src="/App/messages/message-list/message-list.component.js"></script>
<script src="/App/messages/message-detail/message-detail.module.js"></script>
<script src="/App/messages/message-detail/message-detail.component.js"></script>
<script src="/App/messages/message-edit/message-edit.module.js"></script>
<script src="/App/messages/message-edit/message-edit.component.js"></script>
<script src="/App/messages/message-create/message-create.module.js"></script>
<script src="/App/messages/message-create/message-create.component.js"></script>
<script src="/App/messages/message.module.js"></script>
```

How do we get this automatic multiple files in dev mode when using the new build-time Bundler/Minifier without having to both specify each file in my bundle config AND in the main HTML page with an environment tag?
I want it to just work out the paths and give them to be just like the old one. It's hard to debug a single line of JS code when I have no idea which file it's from.

It's written very nicely here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x

Under: **Environment-based bundling and minification**
That we will have to do things like this:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
```

This is a horrible solution when I have a lot of JS files!

Comment: Just a side question, have you ever checked out Source Maps? I haven't really, but Source Maps allow you to basically convert the minified file back to it's formatted state, for exactly those debugging reasons. You need to set `"sourceMap": true` and for debugging for example in Chrome, you can check `Enable Source Maps`, just google it, might be a different but working approach

Comment: Yes, I'm very aware and it works great for debugging MINIFIED files, but all that gives me is a readable error in a file `js.js` which is still not good enough. I want to see the original file it was in.

Comment: Ah OK, I misinterpreted "It's hard to debug a _single line of JS code_", I thought you speak of the minified file :-)

Comment: I've abandoned ASP's bundler and am using Gulp instead now.

Comment: I imagine the solution would be to read in the environment config and check for dev/prod and build bundles accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to disable bundling.
In your RegisterBundles method (BundleConfig class in the App_Start folder).
Add this, it will disable bundling

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

Comment: I do want to disable bundling.. in the new ASP.NET core bundler, not the old one.